# Angularjs $setPristine after http callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found below code is strange. After dataSvc.saves' callback what is `vm.bookDetails = {}; and vm.bookForm.$setPristine` for?

```
angular.module('controllers',[])
  .controller('SecondController', function(dataSvc){
    var vm=this;

    vm.saveData = function () {
      dataSvc.save(vm.bookDetails).then(function(result) {
        vm.bookDetails = {};
        vm.bookForm.$setPristine();
      });
    };

    vm.numberPattern = /^\d*$/;
  });
```

The code is from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/)

Answer (score 1):

The ng-dirty class tells you that the form has been modified by the user, whereas the ng-pristine class tells you that the form has not been modified by the user. So ng-dirty and ng-pristine are two sides of the same story.

The classes are set on any field, while the form has two properties, $dirty and $pristine.

From [Angular.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

$setPristine means

> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state
>   to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class.
>   Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.

You can use the $scope.form.$setPristine() function to reset a form to pristine state. $setPristine() was introduced in the 1.1.x branch of angularjs

**Code Explanation**

```
angular.module('controllers',[])
  .controller('SecondController', function(dataSvc){
    var vm=this;

    vm.saveData = function () {
      dataSvc.save(vm.bookDetails).then(function(result) {
        // This code will reset the form/clear value of all ngmodel
        vm.bookDetails = {};
        // This code will set the validity of the form to invalid state, submitted cannot be made if pristine is set.
        vm.bookForm.$setPristine();
      });
    };

    vm.numberPattern = /^\d*$/;
  });
```

Comment: is it means reset?

Comment: In your code, it is mean the validity of the form, the form cannot be submitted when setPristine is called.